# How to call function from other file

Tags: go

**structure**

```
.
├── deck.go
└── main.go
```

Here is the code in each `.go` file

**main.go**

```
package main

func main() {
    cards := newDeck()
    cards.print()
}
```

**deck.go**

```
package main

import "fmt"

type card struct {
    value string
    suit  string
}

type deck []card

func newDeck() deck {
    cards := deck{}

    cardSuits := []string{"Spades", "Diamonds", "Hearts", "Clubs"}
    cardValues := []string{"Ace", "Two", "Three"}

    for _, suit := range cardSuits {
        for _, value := range cardValues {
            cards = append(cards, card{
                suit:  suit,
                value: value,
            })
        }
    }
    return cards
}

func (d deck) print() {
    for i, card := range d {
        fmt.Printf("%d) %s of %s\n", i, card.value, card.suit)
    }
}
```

Why I can't run main.go file? please help TT

```
❯ go version
go version go1.14.3 darwin/amd64

❯ go run main.go
# command-line-arguments
./main.go:4:11: undefined: newDeck
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Modules in Golang are determined by their parent folder. Across modules, the object must be capitalized to be exported. This is not your case.

Your error is in the compilation stage; this is similar to gcc when it can't find header files. You have to tell the Go compiler to search all files in the current module.

`go run .`

This tells go to include all files in the current (`.`) module (folder). Since `newDeck` is in a different file and the compiler is only running main, it can't find `newDeck`. But if you run all files, it will search and find the func in `deck.go`.

Answer (score 0):

`go run main.go` runs only *that* file. You need to do `go build .` and run the executable.